# old apk can not be deactivated

Tags: android

The Play Store is listing 2 versions of our APK. Both having exactly the same parameters and we can't deactivate the older one. Any idea how to deactivate old release?

I attach images of how it looks in the console:

In App Releases

[image]

In Manage production

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using **staged rollout feature** here, & 3.1.1 is rolled out to **only 20%**

Once you roll out **3.1.1** t to **100%** users, **3.0.1** will get deactivated by itself.
It won't be deactivated before that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I clicked 'Update Rollout' and then 'Update Rollout' in the popup and it fixed the problem.